# button height in percent makes it flat

Tags: css, button, resize

I've been trying to create a button that resizes with screen resolution but it's giving me trouble. For some reason the width is fine - but with all the same code the height won't go above about 5 pixels. This is what I'm doing:

```css
.links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: red 2px solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12%;
  width: 12%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button.links {
  background:#003678;
  border: none;
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<button class="links">
  <a href="Ap.html" id="Ap"></a>
</button>
```

button.links is the parent in this case. I've tried targeting the body element and adding another element to target for size. What's going wrong?

Comment: If the body doesn't have a height this will not work. Also `button` elements should not contain links. They perform two different fuctions.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/BVqVQb

Comment: That fixed it! I didn't realize I had to define the size of every element in the chain. Thank you!